# sklearnのpairwise_kernelsの引数について

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python2

環境: Macbook air, Jupyter-Notebook, Python2.7

Kernel K-meansを実装する際、一部[この方](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/6230787)のコードを参考にしました。
具体的には

```
def _get_kernel(self, X, Y=None):
    if callable(self.kernel):
        params = self.kernel_params or {}
    else:
        params = {"gamma": self.gamma,
                  "degree": self.degree,
                  "coef0": self.coef0}
    return pairwise_kernels(X, Y, metric=self.kernel,
                            filter_params=True, **params)
```

ここの部分です。"callable()"と" **params "の使い方がわかりません。加えて

```
@property
def _pairwise(self):
    return self.kernel == "precomputed"
```

ここもどういったものになっているのかわかりません。具体的には@propertyと"precomputed"です

pythonはおろかプログラミングも完全素人なのでstep by stepで例など込みで教えてもらえると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

以下にリンクを貼っておきます。
[sklearnのリンク](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels.html)

Comment: 「sklearnのリンク」のリンク先が壊れているようです。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。リンクを更新しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### はじめに

分からない関数や書き方があったとき、まずは Python や周辺ライブラリのドキュメントやマニュアルを確認するようにしましょう。基本的にドキュメントを読めば使い方が載っています。「Python callable」や「callable site:docs.python.org/ja」などでウェブ検索するのも有効です。Python 2.7 のドキュメントに限定したい場合は「callable site:docs.python.org/ja/2.7」とできます。

### `**params` について

変数 `params` は `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels` の引数として使われているので、まずはこの関数のドキュメントを確認してみます。scikit-learn 0.19.1 の[ドキュメント](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels.html)には、この関数の説明が以下のように書かれています。

> sklearn.metrics.pairwise.**pairwise_kernels**(*X*, *Y*=*None*, *metric*=*’linear’*, *filter_params*=*False*, *n_jobs*=*1*, ***kwds*)

特に今回注目すべきは `**kwds` という引数です。この引数はどういう意味でしょうか？ 「Python double asterisk」 で検索すると ["What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/5989200) という投稿が見つかります。投稿を元にドキュメントを見ると Python 2.7 ドキュメント [4.7.2 キーワード引数](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) には以下のように書かれています。

> 仮引数の最後に `**name` の形式のものがあると、それまでの仮引数に対応したものを除くすべてのキーワード引数が入った辞書 ([マッピング型 --- dict](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) を参照) を受け取ります。

つまり `**kwds` とは、`Y`, `metric`, `filter_params`, `n_jobs` 以外のキーワード引数を一手に引き受ける辞書型の引数なわけです。実際、`kwds` は keywords の略でしょう。

さてここで `pairwise_kernels` のドキュメントに戻ると、引数の説明欄には以下のように書かれています。

> ****kwds** : optional keyword parameters
>       Any further parameters are passed directly to the kernel function.

したがって `**kwds` は、`pairwise_kernels` で使うカーネル関数に渡すキーワード引数として用意されていることが分かります。用いるカーネル関数によって必要なキーワード引数が違うので、`**kwds` として用意することで対応したということでしょう。

ところで質問文中のコードにおいて `**params` は `**kwds` として渡す引数なのでした。実際 `params` は辞書として以下のように初期化されています。

```
params = {"gamma": self.gamma,
          "degree": self.degree,
          "coef0": self.coef0}
```

`gamma` や `degree` 等のキーワードが具体的にどのように使われるのかは scikit-learn の[こちらのドキュメント](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics)に詳しいです。というわけで `**params` とは、カーネルで使用するパラメータ設定のための任意引数なのです。

### `callable` について

まず `callable` とはどういう関数なのでしょうか。これは Python の組み込み関数で、与えられたオブジェクトが呼び出し可能かを調べるものです。詳細なドキュメントは[こちら](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/functions.html#callable)にあります。

質問文のプログラムでは変数 `self.kernel` が呼び出し可能かどうかを調べています。これは `pairwise_kernel` のキーワード引数 `metric` へ「文字列」または「呼び出し可能オブジェクト」を渡せることに対応しようとしています。`metric` へ `'rbf'` や `'linear'` などの文字列を渡すと scikit-learn 側に用意されたカーネル関数が使われますが、ユーザー側で適当なカーネル関数 `f` を定義して `metric=f` のように渡すこともできる、ということです。

つまり、`self.kernel` が呼び出し可能かどうかで `params` の内容を変えるために組み込み関数 `callable` を使っている、ということです。

### `"precomputed"` について

ところで `self.kernel` に文字列を渡す場合、`"precomputed"` という文字列を渡すと特別に扱われます。具体的には `pairwise_kernel` の[ドキュメント](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels.html)に以下のように書かれています。

> **metric** : string, or callable
>       (前略) If metric is “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a kernel matrix. (後略)

### `@property` について

Python において `@` (アットマーク) から始まる識別子が関数定義の前に置かれているものは、[デコレータ](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/glossary.html#term-decorator)です。`@property` もデコレータの一種です。「python at property」で検索すると ["How does the @property decorator work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/5989200) がヒットします。`@property` について完全に解説すると長いので省きますが、要するにこのクラスのインスタンスが `kkm` だとすると `kkm._pairwise` が使えるようになります。

`@property` の詳しい解説は、Python 2.7 における組み込み関数のドキュメントにある [`property` の解説](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/functions.html#property)をご覧ください。

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございます。僕の調べようが足りないようでした、" ** "についてもdouble asterisk と検索すればよかったのですね、加えて「callable site:docs.python.org/ja」こういった調べ方は初めて知りました、ありがとうございます、お陰様である程度のとこが理解できたと思います、しかし、callable()について「ユーザー側で適当なカーネル関数 f を定義して metric=f のように渡すこともできる」ということはどんなobjectも呼び出し可能ということになりませんか？

Comment: なりません。お手元の Python REPL で `callable(1)` だとか `callable("rbf")` だとかをお試しください。「object」とは何であるかの理解に誤解がありそうです。Python では全てのデータはオブジェクトです。Python ドキュメントだと「3. データモデル」に詳しく書いてあります: https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: メソッドやオブジェクトについてはその名前しか知識はありません、、、ひとまずありがとうございました。ドキュメントを参考に勉強します。

Comment: メソッドやオブジェクトといった言葉は Python に限らず Java や C++、Smalltalk などの[オブジェクト指向プログラミング](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E6%8C%87%E5%90%91%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)言語一般に使われます。ひとまず Python について理解する場合、クラス・ベースのオブジェクト指向プログラミングと呼ばれているパラダイムを理解頂くことになります。何か疑問あれば是非ご質問ください :)

Comment: では１つ質問させて下さい。先程言った通り名前しか知らないと言った状態なんですが、なにから勉強をすればいいでしょう。もちろん対象言語はpythonになると思いますが。今まで広い広いでプログラミングを含めその他の知識を補ってきたので。

Comment: それはなかなか難しいご質問ですね :)　今名前だけ知っている状態でお困りでないのなら、ひとまず詳しいことは置いておいてトップダウンに応用の勉強を継続なさるのも良いと思います。何か困ったことがあるたびに調べれば良い、という立場です。あるいは応用の勉強は一旦止めて基礎からボトムアップに学びたいということであれば、各種チュートリアルや入門書が助けになると思います。幸運なことに Python にはたくさんの入門書があります。たとえば公式の [Python チュートリアル](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/index.html) 第9章「クラス」には、やや網羅的で難しい部分があるものの基礎がちゃんと書いてあるように思います。他にも第三者が書いた平易なものが調べれば見つかります。

Comment: 応用を止めて基礎を固める時間は今はないのでつまづいた時に調べるスタイルを継続しようと思います。夏休みなどの長期休暇に入れば基礎も進めたいと思います。ありがとうございました。